# Socket Policy file for Flash/Java not being recieved by Flash

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, sockets, policy

I'm trying to test a PolicyServer listening on port 843 that handles the sending of policy files so that the client can move onto connecting to the GameServer on a different port.

I'm able to get the following outputs from the server:

Connection to PolicyServer /192.168.1.66:2521

Recieved: policy-file-request

Sending: XML Policy

Connection to GameServer /192.168.1.66:2522

Recieved: policy-file-request

Even through I send a XML Policy it seems to ignore it and request one from the gameServer.
Could it have something to do with the Client/Server being tested on the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just the ports being different?

Comment: Solution: Turns out the write(String) method wasn't flushing fast enough and the request was timing out...